# Protothread call on __LINE__ greater than 256: error: case label value exceeds

Tags: c, embedded, protothread

I use [protothreads](http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/) on my embedded device (STM32, GCC) as it's lightweight, and saves me to handle a complex state machine by myself.

As my main program grows, a PT_* function is called on a line number greater than 256

```
struct pt main_pt;
int main(void)
{
    PT_BEGIN(pt);
    while(true)
    {
        /*... 256 lines further*/
        PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, flag);
        PT_YIELD(pt);
    }
    PT_END(pt);
}
```

And at compile, it throws this error:

```
main.c: In function 'main':    
main.c:256:4: error: case label value exceeds maximum value for type [-Werror]
    PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, flag);
main.c:257:4: error: case label value exceeds maximum value for type [-Werror]
    PT_YIELD(pt);
```

If PT_YIELD or PT_WAIT_UNTIL is placed on a line number lower than 256 it does compile.

Here is snippet for PT_YIELD, PT_WAIT_UNTIL, LC_SET and struct pt:

```
typedef uint32_t lc_t;
struct pt {
  lc_t lc;
};
#define LC_RESUME(s) switch(s) { case 0:
#define LC_SET(s) s = __LINE__; case __LINE__:
#define PT_BEGIN(pt) { unsigned int PT_YIELD_FLAG = 1; LC_RESUME((pt)->lc)
#define PT_WAIT_UNTIL(pt, condition)            \
  do {                      \
    LC_SET((pt)->lc);               \
    if(!(condition)) {              \
      return PT_WAITING;            \
    }                       \
  } while(0)
#define PT_YIELD(pt)                \
  do {                      \
    PT_YIELD_FLAG = 0;              \
    LC_SET((pt)->lc);               \
    if(PT_YIELD_FLAG == 0) {            \
      return PT_YIELDED;            \
    }                       \
  } while(0)
```

Why can't "case __LINE__:" exceed 256 as it's store on uint32_t?

Comment: You're not showing how `LC_RESUME(s)` is used, which seems to be the root cause (it's `switch`ing on an 8-bit value, with `case` labels that exceed this range).

Comment: Please make an [mcve].

Comment: There should never be a reason to write code like this. Use functions instead.

Comment: Protothread, http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/, by Adam Dunkels, not exactly student's poor job.

Comment: maybe `PT_BEGIN(&main_pt);` ? BTW: Why not check the preprocessor output?

Comment: @Tweepy Sorry, but it looks exactly like a student's failed job. The whole library is very poorly written. And it reeks of pre-mature optimization by someone who doesn't understand how compiler function inlining works. The absence of functions doesn't mean that the stack isn't used, and the presence of functions doesn't mean that the stack will be used, that's nonsense assumptions. This should have been written with compiler switches in a common header, to enforce inlining of all functions that need to be inlined etc.

Comment: I'd rather use FreRTOS than this macro overkill. An STM32 has enough resources to run a true multitasking system; stacks are not that large and the Cotex-M is exactly designed to support this kind of OS.

Comment: [CoOS](http://www1.coocox.org/index.html) is nice too.  And [uC/OS-ii](https://www.micrium.com/downloadcenter/micrium-source-code/) is free for educational use.